# Software Certificate Installation Files vulnerablility

Tags: windows

In one of my server audit checklist I came across this one "Are steps taken to ensure that Software Certificate Installation Files are removed?" I want to know what will happen If I don't do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: You fail the audit when you don't.

---

The reason it is an audit item, is that part of proper certificate management is storing them in the correct places with the correct file system permissions. Both common sense and your security policy probably don't include your personal or administrator home directory as the correct place.

Comment: could you please explain me little more brief?

Comment: Without more context that is difficult for me. I would recommend contacting the author of **your** audit list as he/she is probably in a better position to place that item from your checklist in the correct context for your organisation. - From my perspective certificates should only be *stored once* on production systems and each additional unneeded copy doubles the chance that it will be exposed, invalidating your security chain.